# How to write script to bind and unbind to stop and start click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to bind(enable click event) and unbind(stop click event) jquery accordian depends on condition.If i selected value 1 from dropdown box i want to enable third link accordian if i select value 2 i want to unbind third accordian.How do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/nh0kcuop/1/

Script:

```
//On click any <h3> within the container
$('#container h3').click(function(e) {

//Close all <div> but the <div> right after the clicked <a>
$(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('fast');

//Toggle open/close on the <div> after the <h3>, opening it if not open.
$(e.target).next('div').slideToggle('fast');

});



$('#status').on('change',function(){

if(   $(this).val() == 1 ){

$('.text').bind('click');

}

if(   $(this).val() == 2 ){

$('.text').unbind('click');

}

});
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code

Comment: try with $(document).on(event,selector, function) for binding and unbinding the click handler

Comment: @JBDouble05:  JSfiddle added

Answer (score 0):

Hi updated your fiddle you can use "on" ond off to enabled the click function

```
//On click any <h3> within the container
$('#container h3').click(function(e) {

    //Close all <div> but the <div> right after the clicked <a>
    $(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('fast');

    //Toggle open/close on the <div> after the <h3>, opening it if not open.
    $(e.target).next('div').slideToggle('fast');

});



$('#status').on('change',function(){
console.log("status changed :" + $(this).val());
if($(this).val() == 1 ){
$('#container h3').on('click',function(e) {
    //Close all <div> but the <div> right after the clicked <a>
    $(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('fast');
    //Toggle open/close on the <div> after the <h3>, opening it if not open.
    $(e.target).next('div').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
}
if($(this).val() == 2 ){
$('#container h3').off('click');

}

});
```

please visit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/nh0kcuop/8/)

Comment: means you need only third accordion open when second value is selected?

Comment: Yes..Pls do not use $('#container h3').on('click',function(e) {..click event again...can we use $('#container h3').on('click'); instead of..